# How to find the size (in MB/GB) of materialized view in Azure Dedicated SQL Pool / Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I want to display list of materialized views in the Database and Size of the physical storage in MB/GB. It would be great if I get some SQL query for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `sp_spaceused`  or  `DBCC PDW_SHOWSPACEUSED`  to get the space consumed by a materialized view.

Results - sp_spaceused

[image]

Results - DBCC PDW_SHOWSPACEUSED (space displayed in KB)

[image]

Checkout below documentations for details:

1. [sp_spaceused](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-spaceused-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true)
2. [DBCC PDW_SHOWSPACEUSED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-pdw-showspaceused-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true)

Refer ([Original](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/507801/how-to-find-the-size-in-mbgb-of-materialized-view.html))